# Transposing rows into a single column while copying data in other columns

Tags: excel, vba, transpose

I'm extracting data from the SQL and some rows need to be transposed into a column while copying the other data that is unique for that table
Need a formula to read all the columns and paste new rows and copy data.
This is just an example,depending on the days I need as many rows in one column to be transposed. Original Data is in 50,000+ Rows
Any suggestions are welcomed

**Before**

```
Order   Line    Item    Day Day2   Day3  Day4  Day5  Day6   Day7
2000    1      Apple    Mon Tue    Wed         Fri   Sat    Sun  
2000    2      Orange   Mon               Thu               Sun  
etc...
```

**After**

```
Order   Line    Item    Day
2000    1       Apple   Mon
2000    1       Apple   Tue
2000    1       Apple   Wed
2000    1       Apple   Fri
2000    1       Apple   Sat
2000    1       Apple   Sun
2000    2      Orange   Mon
2000    2      Orange   Thu
2000    2      Orange   Sun
```

Comment: You can do this with a Class.  Create a user defined object, and add the days to it as a collection.  What happens if there are more than seven days listed?

Comment: Hi Ron,thanks for the answer but I have never used Class,I can only write simple queries, I'm just a functional consultant:). There is only 7 days but data is stored as a number 1-127. I had to convert it into binary,1 is 0000001 as  Sunday and 127 is Any day of the week. Others are a combination of different days. I'm importing data into Netsuite and in the current customization each day has to be a separate line unfortunately. Thanks for the suggestion,btw, i will consult with google and try to figure it out:)

Comment: Suggest you start with Chip Pearson's [Introduction to Classes](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/Classes.aspx).  Also, depending on your precise requirements, you may run out of room with only a bit more than 10^6 lines per worksheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a quick and dirty way to do it. This may take a few minutes to run but that is what it takes when dealing with that many rows.

50,000x7 = 350,000 rows so you are fine to put the output on another worksheet if you have any recent version of Excel.  I'm on 2010 and the row limit is 1,048,576.

This assumes the data is on Sheet1 and we will write it out to Sheet2.

In you VBA IDE go to the tools menu and select references. Select "Microstoft ActiveX data objects 2.8 Library.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim ws   As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim rs   As New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim lRow As Long

    'Add fields to your recordset for storing data.  This is how we will store the original data so we can process it after we read it.
    With rs
        .Fields.Append "Order", adInteger
        .Fields.Append "Line", adInteger
        .Fields.Append "Item", adChar, 25
        .Fields.Append "Day", adChar, 10
        .Fields.Append "Day2", adChar, 10
        .Fields.Append "Day3", adChar, 10
        .Fields.Append "Day4", adChar, 10
        .Fields.Append "Day5", adChar, 10
        .Fields.Append "Day6", adChar, 10
        .Fields.Append "Day7", adChar, 10
        .Open
    End With

    lRow = 2 'Start at two if there is a header row...
    Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    ws.Activate

    'Loop through the rows and record the data
    Do While lRow <= ws.UsedRange.Rows.count

        If ws.Range("A" & lRow).Value <> "" Then
            rs.AddNew
            rs.Fields("Order").Value = ws.Range("A" & lRow).Value
            rs.Fields("Line").Value = ws.Range("B" & lRow).Value
            rs.Fields("Item").Value = ws.Range("C" & lRow).Value
            rs.Fields("Day").Value = ws.Range("D" & lRow).Value
            rs.Fields("Day2").Value = ws.Range("E" & lRow).Value
            rs.Fields("Day3").Value = ws.Range("F" & lRow).Value
            rs.Fields("Day4").Value = ws.Range("G" & lRow).Value
            rs.Fields("Day5").Value = ws.Range("H" & lRow).Value
            rs.Fields("Day6").Value = ws.Range("I" & lRow).Value
            rs.Fields("Day7").Value = ws.Range("J" & lRow).Value
            rs.Update
        End If

        lRow = lRow + 1
        ws.Range("A" & lRow).Activate
    Loop

    'Switch to the second worksheet
    Set ws = Nothing
    Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
    ws.Activate

    lRow = 1

    If rs.RecordCount > 0 Then
        rs.MoveFirst
    End If

    Do While rs.EOF = False

        If Trim(rs.Fields("Day").Value) <> "" Then
            ws.Range("A" & lRow).Value = rs.Fields("Order").Value
            ws.Range("B" & lRow).Value = rs.Fields("Line").Value
            ws.Range("C" & lRow).Value = rs.Fields("Item").Value
            ws.Range("D" & lRow).Value = rs.Fields("Day").Value
            lRow = lRow + 1
        End If

        If Trim(rs.Fields("Day2").Value) <> "" Then
            ws.Range("A" & lRow).Value = rs.Fields("Order").Value
            ws.Range("B" & lRow).Value = rs.Fields("Line").Value
            ws.Range("C" & lRow).Value = rs.Fields("Item").Value
            ws.Range("D" & lRow).Value = rs.Fields("Day2").Value
            lRow = lRow + 1
        End If

        If Trim(rs.Fields("Day3").Value) <> "" Then
            ws.Range("A" & lRow).Value = rs.Fields("Order").Value
            ws.Range("B" & lRow).Value = rs.Fields("Line").Value
            ws.Range("C" & lRow).Value = rs.Fields("Item").Value
            ws.Range("D" & lRow).Value = rs.Fields("Day3").Value
            lRow = lRow + 1
        End If

        If Trim(rs.Fields("Day4").Value) <> "" Then
            ws.Range("A" & lRow).Value = rs.Fields("Order").Value
            ws.Range("B" & lRow).Value = rs.Fields("Line").Value
            ws.Range("C" & lRow).Value = rs.Fields("Item").Value
            ws.Range("D" & lRow).Value = rs.Fields("Day4").Value
            lRow = lRow + 1
        End If

        If Trim(rs.Fields("Day5").Value) <> "" Then
            ws.Range("A" & lRow).Value = rs.Fields("Order").Value
            ws.Range("B" & lRow).Value = rs.Fields("Line").Value
            ws.Range("C" & lRow).Value = rs.Fields("Item").Value
            ws.Range("D" & lRow).Value = rs.Fields("Day5").Value
            lRow = lRow + 1
        End If

        If Trim(rs.Fields("Day6").Value) <> "" Then
            ws.Range("A" & lRow).Value = rs.Fields("Order").Value
            ws.Range("B" & lRow).Value = rs.Fields("Line").Value
            ws.Range("C" & lRow).Value = rs.Fields("Item").Value
            ws.Range("D" & lRow).Value = rs.Fields("Day6").Value
            lRow = lRow + 1
        End If

        If Trim(rs.Fields("Day7").Value) <> "" Then
            ws.Range("A" & lRow).Value = rs.Fields("Order").Value
            ws.Range("B" & lRow).Value = rs.Fields("Line").Value
            ws.Range("C" & lRow).Value = rs.Fields("Item").Value
            ws.Range("D" & lRow).Value = rs.Fields("Day7").Value
            lRow = lRow + 1
        End If

        ws.Range("A" & lRow).Activate
        rs.MoveNext
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Mathew,thanks for the code but unfortunately it doesn't work. Error Multiple-Step operation generated errors. Check each status value. Stops at Ln 31  rs.Fields("Order").Value = ws.Range("A" & lRow).Value  Any thoughts?

Comment: It could be a few things.  Do you have a header row, does row 1 columnA have the word Order in it? if so change lRow = 1 to lRow = 2.  I declared rs field "order" as an integer so that would cause the multi step error.  That error basically means that you are trying to load a string into an int or something like that.  If no header row, are the order numbers not ints? Is something in column A not an int? A char or a blank? We can change  .Fields.Append "Order", adInteger to .Fields.Append "Order", adChar, 20

Comment: To expand on that a bit, the definition of the fields in 'With rs' has to comply with the data that you load into them.  So without seeing the data, I can only guess as to what to define them as. The multi step error means we are trying to load data into a field that doesn't comply.

Comment: lRow = 1 to lRow = 2 Fixed it. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can modify your SQL query to directly return the results using UNION, for example? :

```
SELECT 'Order', Line, Item, Day1 AS Day 
FROM Table1 as T1
WHERE NOT IsNull(Day1)
UNION
SELECT 'Order', Line, Item, Day2 AS Day
FROM Table1
WHERE NOT IsNull(Day2)
UNION
SELECT 'Order', Line, Item, Day3 AS Day
FROM Table1
WHERE NOT IsNull(Day3)
UNION
SELECT 'Order', Line, Item, Day4 AS Day
FROM Table1
WHERE NOT IsNull(Day4)
UNION
SELECT 'Order', Line, Item, Day5 AS Day
FROM Table1
WHERE NOT IsNull(Day5)
UNION
SELECT 'Order', Line, Item, Day6 AS Day
FROM Table1
WHERE NOT IsNull(Day6)
UNION
SELECT 'Order', Line, Item, Day7 AS Day
FROM Table1
WHERE NOT IsNull(Day7)
```

Comment: Thanks Vincent but i already connected 7 tables to get this result and then I use other queries and combine data in excel with INDEX and MATCH on join fields.